# Sharing Object Definition in Javascript server/client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a simple turn based multiplayer game. I will have some "unit" objects I want pass back and forth. I wanted to define the definition of the object only once. In C++ I would use a header file, and in Java I could implement them them, but in Javascript I don't know how I could achieve this.

I could simply define everything twice, but I have a feeling this might come up again in my future at some point, and I rather learn to deal with it properly now. I'm using Nodejs and Javascript.

As a note, I thinking I could just do a simple HTML  but I was having a hard time figuring out how to do the same thing on the server.js, and I'm not sure if this is even how I should be handling this.

Comment: Javascript is dynamic, creating a "defintition" isn't something that can be done well since everything can be changed so an interface or a definition is meaningless. It's impossible to enforce an object structure unless you use something like [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if I understand your question correctly. But I would just define the unit Object in a file and export it from there. You could use `Object.freeze()` or `Object.seal()` (depending on your use case), which will prevent the Object from being modified/props from being added. Also if you want to initialize it with dynamic values, you would define a function returning the sealed/frozen Object:

```
const unit = Object.seal({
  name: 'hello'
  ....
});

export default unit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a module with your logic and `require` it, both in the front end and in the server. This way you will have your logic defined in a single place, reused wherever you need it.

Have a look at http://browserify.org/ for the front end.